# How to do a MySQL query without creating temp tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, temp-tables

I have a bit of a situation here.

I have a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (testrecurring.id), testrecurring.cxl, testci.cd
FROM testci, testrecurring 
WHERE (testci.id = testrecurring.id) 
AND testci.x_origin='1' 
ORDER BY testrecurring.id DESC;
```

Now, if a var is not set, I need to do a select on this query, and here is the catch. I need to exclude some id's. Here is how I'm doing it now.

I create a table with that query: `create table xxx SELECT * .....` and now the results from my previous query are inside another table called `xxx`.

Then:

```
if (!isset($var)) {
    $delete = mysql_query("delete from xxx USING xxx, future_recurring where xxx.id = future_recurring.id");
}
```

and after the records have been deleted I do my final `select * from xxx`.

This works just fine, the only thing is that I need to redo all this logic by not creating any tables. Maybe doing some joins, I'm not sure how to proceed.

I hope this is not very confusing.

Any ideas?

Comment: it might work, but it's not the way to go. don't create tables from your tables, you can use mysql views instead (create view). in your case you can implement it without creating a table/view. you can do SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE tbl.id IN (SELECT * FROM tbl2...)

Comment: how would i accommodate that delete statement. basically i need to exclude some id's based on some other id's from another table..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And now how about this?:

```
SELECT tr.id, tr.cxl, tci.cd
FROM testci AS tci 
INNER JOIN testrecurring AS tr
    ON tci.id = tr.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN future_recurring AS fr
    ON tr.id = fr.id
WHERE tci.x_origin='1' 
    AND fr.id IS NULL
GROUP BY tr.id, tr.cxl, tci.cd
ORDER BY tr.id DESC
```

This only includes results in which the testrecurring.id is NOT FOUND in future_recurring

Comment: alright, i edited the script a bi on the select. instead of * i have `DISTINCT (testrecurring.id), testrecurring.cxl, testci.cd`

Comment: `future_recurring.id` is found inside `future_recurring` table and first i do `testci.id = testrecurring.id` then based on those id's i match them with the ones from `future_recurring`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a where condition to exclude the rows you don't want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM testci
JOIN testrecurring on testrecurring.id = testci.id
WHERE testci.x_origin='1' 
      AND testci.id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM future_recurring)
ORDER BY testrecurring.id DESC;
```

Or you could try this which might give better performance:

```
SELECT * 
FROM testci
JOIN testrecurring on testrecurring.id = testci.id
LEFT JOIN future_recurring on future_recurring.id = testci.id
WHERE testci.x_origin='1' 
      AND future_recurring id IS null
ORDER BY testrecurring.id DESC;
```

Although, if your indexes are good and sane and your data sets aren't enormous then the performance should be close.

Comment: i edited the script a bi on the select. instead of * i have `DISTINCT (testrecurring.id), testrecurring.cxl, testci.cd`